# Run a project before starting .Net Unit Tet

Tags: c#, .net, rest, unit-testing, testing

I have 3 projects made with .Net 7.0

The first is a REST API.
The second is a REST Client.
And the third is a Unit Test project.

When I start the unit test I would like to start the server with a defined port number.
Then my unit test use the REST Client to talk to the REST API.

How can I start a web service before my unit test start ?

Comment: Don't misuse your unit tests to test things outside your control. Unit tests shouldn't be used to test networking, etc. That's what integration tests are for.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, from Debug menu chose Start Without Debugging. Or right click on the web service project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to test the logic contained in your controller actions you'll want to use [integration tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0), not unit tests. With integration tests you can set up a WebApplicationFactory that works similarly to a HttpClientFactory. With this, you create a client connected to the API that lets you simulate requests as they would be in a production environment in order to test how all components work together.

Integration testing is more complicated to set up, so if you're just getting started with this project, I'd recommend moving the logic in your controller actions into a separate helper class, and run the unit tests on those instead.